# android sqllite get rows which are valid in current day

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

```
public Cursor getRowsBetweenDate(Date startAt, Date endAt) {
        String selection = KEY_START_AT + " >= time('now', 'localtime') AND " + KEY_END_AT + " <= time('now', 'localtime')";
        return sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, null, selection, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

but i want the whole day, not valid just now. I want to get all rows that are valid this day. So from 00:00 to 23:59:59

How can I do this?

EDIT:

thank you. Any what if day is not now but some other day as input param?

Comment: you might use `date('now', 'localhost')` instead of `time('now', 'localhost')` for getting current date.

Comment: thank you i will try. And if my date is stored as UTC then i need date('now', 'localtime')?

Comment: yeah. try and let us know.

Comment: thank you. Any what if day is not now but some other day as input param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
String where = "strftime('%d.%m.%Y', date(?)) = strftime('%d.%m.%Y', 'now')";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
String [] whereArgs = {dateFormat.format(KEY_END_AT) };
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, null, where , whereArgs, null,
            null, null);
```

All of this is typed out only via searchign through documentation and I might have some stupid typo. Please write back if any problems.

**EDIT** Actually Harry Joy's idea seems easier, but I will be leaving my comment here, becasue it might be useful if you are interested in grouping in something other than days.